# No Data Received

Tags: html

Out of the blue, around 40% of my website's community can no longer visit, saying they're getting "No Data Received" errors. We've taken our firewall offline, tried going through systems such as Cloudflare and checked our .htaccess to no avail.

I've asked affected users to traceroute but the weird thing is it looks like it's being stopped at ISP level.

Can anyone suggest other things that may be causing this error?

Comment: Can you see anything in logs?

Comment: You may consider to check at http://www.serverfault.com which is a specific site for server administration

Comment: If you haven't changed anything recently, speak to your hosting company.